# How to check if JSON data is loaded

Tags: vue.js, axios

I use axios to fetch my JSON file en vuex for using the fetched data over multiple components.
The thing is that my page renders before all data is loaded.
The following works because I delayed the rendering by 2 seconds, without this timeout it would result in an error.
I would like to do this the proper way but am not sure how to do it.

**STORE.JS**

```
Vue.use(Vuex);    
const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        poss: null
    },
    getters: {
        NAME: state => {
            return state.name
        },
        POSS: state => {
            return state.poss
        }
    },
    mutations: {
        SET_POSS : (state,payload) => {
          state.poss = payload
        },
        ADD_POSS : (state,payload) => {
          state.poss.push(payload)
        },
      },
      actions:{
       GET_POSS : async (context,payload) => {
          let { data } = await axios.get("json/poss.json")
          context.commit('SET_POSS',data)
       },
       SAVE_POSS : async (context,payload) => {
          let { data } = await axios.post("json/poss.json")
          context.commit('ADD_POSS',payload)
       }
    }
});
```

**COMPONENT.VUE**

```
module.exports = {          
        mounted:function(){
            var self = this;
            setTimeout(function () {
                self.mkPageload()
            }, 2000);
       },
       methods: {
            mkPageload: function(){ 
                let positions = this.$store.getters.POSS.pos            
                Object.keys(positions).forEach(key => { 
                   // rendering
                }
            }
       }
}
```

The desired result is that the page is only rendered after all data from the JSON file has been loaded.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to solve this.

- You could use wait / async in your component.

  ```
  async mounted () {
     await userStore.getAll()
     // access getter and render
  },
  ```
- Your could watch vuex variable like (could be done without async but I like to add them)

  ```
  async mounted () {
     await userStore.getAll()
  },
  computed: {
  ...mapGetters('users')
  }, 
  watch: {
      users(newValue, oldValue) {
         ....
         // render
      }
  }
  ```

dont'forget to import the mapGetters: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html

Comment: Code formatting isn't working in my post if anyone knows why ...?

Comment: To get [a code block inside a list](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#advanced-lists), you need to indent the code by an extra 4 spaces (or one tab) for each level of list nesting. Otherwise the parser assumes that you're just trying to continue the list item after a paragraph break.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, I've seen some examples on the internet, but they are all different from my setup. Could you tell for example how the first option would look like in my situation?

Comment: @MK01111000 I updated my code examples, hope this clarifies it a bit

Comment: To be honest I still have no clue how to use this in my code. I'll have to do some more researching. Thanks for your help